# Scsi Path is failing

Tags: linux, networking, scsi, multipath

I am very new to multipathing concept. I am trying to troubleshoot an issue with multipathing however, I am not sure if it's an issue with multipath configuration.

Server is connected to storage over iscsi, there are 4 different Ethernet ports which are connected to server for storage connection. Eth1 and Eth2 : 192.x.x.x (2 IP's in same subnet) Eth5 and Eth6 : 10.x.x.x (2 IP's in same subnet) these ip's are not in any vlan.

None of the Ethernet card IP config have gateway. I think it's working on broadcast.

Here is the configuration on server for multipath.

device
  {
     vendor   "NETAPP"
     product  "LUN"
     path_grouping_policy    group_by_prio
     features                "0"
     prio                    "ontap"
     path_selector           "round-robin 0"
     failback                immediate
     hardware_handler        "0"
     rr_weight               uniform
     rr_min_io               128
 }

Post running this command "iscsiadm --mode session" I am only able to see 2 paths i.e Eth5 and Eth6. why I am unable to see path for Eth0 and Eth1 Should be able to see 4 paths or 2 paths are correct. I have checked messages, unable to find anything.

Kindly advise, If above configuration is correct or If wrong, what things need to correct.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the ouptut of "multipath -ll"?

Comment: @batistuta09 I am able to see all LUNS, below is the o/p for one of them

3600a0980383034715a3f4662364b4a68 dm-7 NETAPP,LUN C-Mode  
size=10G features='0' hwhandler='0' wp=rw    
|-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=4 status=active    
| `- 1:0:0:11 sdd  8:48   active ready running             
`-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=1 status=enabled       
  `- 2:0:0:11 sde  8:64   active ready running

Comment: Please could you add the addresses and subnet masks of **all** the NICs on the initiator and the target?